# Change Mailbox atrributes in exchange or in active directory

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010

I would like to change some attributes from some Exchange Accounts ( department etc.)

Should I do this with the exchange console or directly in the active directory?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter. You can use either EMC or ADUC. Both tools make changes in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should always make these changes via Active Directory.

You could always use a Powershell script if there are a lot of modifications to make.

Comment: How come? What is the reason? I use EMC regularly, so I'd like to understand why I shouldn't.